# why transpose convolution is called "transpose"

Tags: cnn, convolutional-neural-network

https://d2l.ai/chapter_computer-vision/transposed-conv.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

I understand what transpose convolution does, but I am confused about the name of 'transpose'.

In linear algebra, transpose is the action which flips a matrix over its diagonal;, which is absolutely what transpose convolution does in this case.

So why named as transpose convolution？

Comment: Check [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AyMR4IhSWQ&list=PL5-TkQAfAZFbzxjBHtzdVCWE0Zbhomg7r&index=16) from 48:40

Answer (score 0):

Transpose in mathematics means to change the order of matrix in an opposite way, the same notion carries here but not the exact sense, you are talking about.

The same problem exists with the word 'convolution', it means something else in mathematics. What is done in deep learning in name of convolution is cross-correlation in mathematics.

Comment: still doesn't explain why it's called transpose

Comment: It is a misrepresentation as I said above.

Comment: It actually isn't. If you think of convolution as a sparse matrix multiplication, then transposed convolution is just the transposed matrix multiplication, see supplementary materials of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05110.pdf

Comment: You can suit your own narrative however you want. But the axiomatic definition of transpose (the transpose of a matrix is an operator which flips a matrix over its diagonal) doesn't match with what has happened. In a vague sense, it is related hence the reason it was named like that.

Comment: transposed matrix multiplication matches exactly what happens in transposed convolution, read the paper above, and watch the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AyMR4IhSWQ&list=PL5-TkQAfAZFbzxjBHtzdVCWE0Zbhomg7r&index=17&ab_channel=MichiganOnline) at 48:40 as suggested above, in particular the slide at 55:30